# Find/Write a pattern

Tags: pattern-matching

I should find a pattern for the following expression:
`expr = {a^2, a^b, x^4, (x - 1)^2};`

And that should be the result: `{2 a, a^(-1 + b) b, 4 x^3, 2 (-1 + x)}`

Can anybody help me please?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a routine homework question

Comment: @Daniel Sorry that I did not recognize it as such.

Answer (score 4):

```
{a^2, a^b, x^4, (x - 1)^2} /. x_^y_ :> y*x^(y - 1)
```

> ```
> {2 a, a^(-1 + b) b, 4 x^3, 2 (-1 + x)}
> ```